# Equivalent of row_number in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to run a query where I assign integers based on the order they appeared in the query. I'd like it to work to the effect of:

`MATCH users RETURN users ORDER BY created_at SET user.number=ROW_NUMBER()`

Is there a way to do this in a single query? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by playing a bit with a collection :

```
MATCH (n:User)
WITH n
ORDER BY n.created_at
WITH collect(n) as users
UNWIND range(0, size(users)-1) as pos
SET (users[pos]).number = pos
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Is UNWIND effectively looping through each value from 0...size-1? UNWIND seems almost like a for loop where pos is the counter.

Comment: UNWIND loops through any collection, here we build a collection of integers representing keys of the users collection